# Catch program crash when there is no terminal

Tags: kde, xfce, programming, crash, debugging

This question may belong to Unix/Linux in general, but I guess the answer is dependent on distro or desktop environment [I use KDE and Xfce so I would like an answer that is applicable on booth].

Consider this simple GTK app:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void print_hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
    {
    g_print ("Hello World\n");

//  Intentional crash
    int* badfood=NULL;
    *badfood=1;
    }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    GtkWidget* button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Crash this app");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
    }
```

The program will crash with SIGSEGV when the user clicks "Crash this app". If run from the terminal, I get a notice:

```
$ ~/Skrivbord/gtktest/test 
Hello World
Segmenteringsfel (minnesutskrift skapad)
```

And I am happy, but starting it through the launch box...

[image: KDE launch box]

The window only disappears without any visible notice about a program crash. In the latter case, I want a message appear telling me something like

> `~/Skrivbord/gtktest/test` has caused a segmentation fault

much like I get in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading `man 5 core` I have found what happens when a program crash. By setting `core_pattern`, I can launch something else than `apport` that `fork`-`setuid`-`setgit`-`exec` `zenity`.